# Client SSL certificate location

Tags: linux, security, ssl, storage, client-certificates

I am building a secure app to transmit data through a single port. Access to the port are already managed. However, a certificate and private key are needed for the transmission to be secure. Where and how to store the files?

1. At /etc/ssl/certs/.key .pem with permission 400. The certificate would be thus secure, but the app not very flexible.
2. At a location pointed by a config file. The thing is, it is a bit weird to create a config file with only one option.
3. At a location point by an argument to the script. While this should be used with an other option, it raise the problem of the number of files. The client would need to point to two files or the app would be less flexible because it would need to deduce the key file with the certificate location.

What way(s) are recommended?

Comment: My option is `~/.<appname>/key.pem` with 700 mask for `<appname>`. Path `/etc/ssl/certs/.key` is too systemwide.

Comment: I like Pak Uula's suggestion, this way, each user can have a different certificate if required.  Any non-global file should be stored under the user's home directory, in a `.something` directory.

Comment: Ok thanks. And I would not be considered bad practice to hardcode the name?

Comment: You put your client certificate in protected storage, like a Keychain (OS X, Android) or Protected Storage (Windows). You don't leave it hanging around the file system.